# What is the value of $f(x)$ if $f\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)=x+2$?

Tags: functions

> $f\left(\dfrac{1-x}{1+x}\right)=x+2$. Find the value of $f(x)$.

How can I use inverse function method to solve this type of problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:

If you set $g(x)=\dfrac{1-x}{1+x}$, note that $\;g\bigl(g(x)\bigr)=x$, so
$$f(x)= f\biggl(\frac{1-g(x)}{1+g(x)}\biggr).$$

Comment: Can you give me one more hint?

Comment: I've added another detail.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Subsitute $\frac{1-x}{1+x}=y$ and solve for x. Use cross multiplication and solve the resulting equation.

Comment: This is exactly what i have written! Thank you!

Comment: Can you give me one more hint? I am still struggling.

Comment: $1-x=(1+x)y$. Solve for x

Comment: OP: Then observe that $f(y) = x+2$, Replace the $x$ in the right-hand side with your expression in terms of $y$.  That should do it.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(\frac{x-1}{x+1})=x+2\ \ \Rightarrow \ \ f(\frac{2}{x+1}-1)=x+2$$
$$\mathbf{put}\  y\ =\ \frac{2}{x+1}\ \ \Rightarrow \ f(y-1)\ =\ \frac{2}{y} +\ 1$$
$$\mathbf{put}\ z\ =\ y-1,\ \ \Rightarrow f(z)\ =\ \frac{2}{z+1}\ +\ 1$$
$$\Rightarrow\ f(x)\ =\ \frac{x+3}{x+1}$$